# Using values from a rest.response

Tags: json, rest, go, unmarshalling

I am receiving a rest.Response back from a function and want to use two of the return fields to send customised data to another service.

```
var reply email.SendTemplateResponseBody

    response, err := s.DynamicTemplateEmail(request)

    if err != nil {
        reply = email.SendTemplateResponseBody{
                Status: int32(response.StatusCode),
                Message: "It didn't work",
            }
    } else {
        reply = email.SendTemplateResponseBody{
                Status:  int32(response.StatusCode),
                Message: "It worked!",
            }
        }
```

I'm using validation on the fields, so want to grab the returned error from the Body and use it in the above code.

The 'response':

```
{StatusCode:400 Body:{"errors":[{"message":"The from object must be provided for every email send. It is an object that requires the email parameter, but may also contain a name parameter.  e.g. {\"email\" : \"example@example.com\"}
```

Can this be done without unmarshalling? And if so, is this the correct way to do so?

Comment: "Can this be done without unmarshalling?" No. But clearly you have already done that, so I don't really understand the question.

Comment: @Peter Is there a way of accessing that specific key value pair without using the unmarshal function.

Comment: Again, no, because before you unmarshal you just have a byte slice or an io.Reader.

Comment: The act of extracting that data _is_ unmarshaling. So, no, there is no alternative, even if you don't use the standard unmarshaling functionality.

Comment: @Flimzy misunderstanding on my part, thanks for clarification

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Can this be done without unmarshalling?

No.

Comment: Not the most fleshed out answer but it stops me from barking up other trees, so thanks!